# Return problems in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, return, sudoku

I am quite new to python and programming in general, and as a first project I am working on a sudoku solver : I am using backtracking and it seems to work when used on its own, but I want to incorporate it in a larger program.

The problem is that when I simply print() the grid after solving it, it works just fine (as per the following code sample) :

```
def solve(grid):
    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(9):
            if grid[y][x] == 0:
                for n in range(1,10):
                    if possible(grid,x,y,n):
                        grid[y][x] = n
                        solve(grid)
                        grid[y][x] = 0
                return
    print(numpy.matrix(grid))
    c = raw_input("More? [y/n]\n")
    if c == 'n':
        quit()
    else:
        pass
solve(grid)
```

But when I try to return the grid instead of printing it, it just doesn't work and returns [[None]] :

```
def solve(grid):
    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(9):
            if grid[y][x] == 0:
                for n in range(1,10):
                    if possible(grid,x,y,n):
                        grid[y][x] = n
                        solve(grid)
                        grid[y][x] = 0
                return
    return grid
print(numpy.matrix(solve(grid)))
```

Any ideas and explanations about this ? How can I just call the function, give it my grid, and make it return a solved grid ?

Comment: You have an empty return on line 10 of your second code snippet.

Comment: Yes but it is part of the recursion process, plus there is one on the first code snippet and it works

Answer (score 0):

If first condition evaluates to true:

```py
if grid[y][x] == 0:
```

solve function returns `None`, not `grid`.